# How should I best query my dataset from VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, dataset

I have a VB.Net data set that contains data from multiple tables.  Does anyone have any good suggestions on how to query data out of the dataset.  I want to run SQL-like queries on a dataset to extract data that fits a certain "`where`" statement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `DataTable.Select()` method.

Here is some information from the official [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select.aspx).

As said in later posts, Linq is another possibility and will probably give you much more versatility, which you may not need depending upon your own requirements.

Comment: looks like a good viable option will check it out tomorrow and report back if it works for what I need.

Comment: this method worked best for me.  it was simple and got what i needed done.  easy to understand to.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using .NET 3.5, you can use [LINQ to DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977.aspx).

Basically you use [DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.aspx) (an extension method) to access the rows as an `IEnumerable<DataRow>` and then you can use normal LINQ to Object operators. The [`DataRowExtensions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowextensions.aspx) extensions make this simpler.

If you're using a strongly typed `DataSet`, the queries look even better.

I prefer this option over `DataTable.Select` - all that messing about with escaping, formatting string queries etc feels like a real backward step.

Comment: looks like a good viable option will check it out tomorrow and report back if it works for what I need.

Answer (score 2):

You should try using Linq.

It will provide you lots of features regarding querying your objects.

try getting more information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa904594.aspx

Or google for Linq to DataSets